# Jenkins returning error after trying to download SonarQube Runner

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using sonarQube to run on my job. I tried using an environment variable for sonar_runner_home but did not work. Now I'm trying to run all the dependencies needed via an option that returns this error:

```
 /ScanReport.xml]
 FATAL: Failed to install       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/3.2.0.1227/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227.zip to C:\Users\MyComputerUser\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonaerQube
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:859)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/3.2.0.1227/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227.zip to C:\Users\MyComputerUser\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonaerQube
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:938)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:846)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:48)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.BuilderUtils.getBuildTool(BuilderUtils.java:56)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:265)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:247)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1806)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at    hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
   Finished: FAILURE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2oKb.png)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: That stack trace talks about SSL versions I guess. That could mean for example that your server is using outdated security certificates, or libraries ... something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to Jenkins java properties. If you are using Windows then you can do that in jenkins.xml file under install location of Jenkins.

Comment: Im using a .war to use it

Comment: Tell me what operating system are you using. If you are using Windows then you should have file called jenkins.xml. It defines arguments passed to java when running jenkins.war.